# What is a snake and what are they used for?

Tags: mixing

I saw this referenced in a question about setting up microphones for drums.

It seemed to be for collecting signals from multiple mics and passing them on to a single channel in a mixing desk. Is it basically a mixing desk with less features and a different shape?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A snake is simply several cables bunched together.  It is typically used to route all or most of the signals between the stage and a mixing desk.

[image]

There is usually a box at the stage end to plug all of the microphones and instruments into and simply cables at the other end to plug into the mixer.

Here is a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_cable) with more technical details on the cable itself.

Answer (score 4):

A snake:

[image]

Not really to pass it to a single channel or change effects around or anything - more of a organizational tool; keeping the studio / recording area tidy.